# Autodesk Forge view 2 linked Revit file

Tags: javascript, automation, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-data-management

recently I have managed to translate any Revit file: https://github.com/abedaarabi/forge

to the web viewer using Autodesk Forge, my issue that I have to link Revit files for example structure and MEP, I would like to show both of them to the web viewer in BIM 360 it called Design collaboration, also I guess there' not Api supports this case.

are there any ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

To link Revit models in BIM360 Docs, please check the official here: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim360-docs-setting-external-references-between-files-upload-linked-files

Unfortunately, there is no API available for accessing the C4R model(saying Design Collaboration currently. Now the only way to set them up is to do the followings as I know:

1. Open the host C4R model with the Revit (Working Sharing)
2. Link other C4R models to the host
3. Save and sync with the central
4. Publish a new model version to BIM360 Docs

After translating, you would the linked model contents appear in the host model.